# Is it possible to use reflections-maven to scan for classes inside jars in web-Inf/lib?

Tags: class, maven, jar, reflections

I need to create a list of subclasses for a particular interface during maven build process and then use that at runtime to load those classes. I have added reflections-maven (from google code reflections) in my webapp pom but during maven build, its only including the classes from the web application and not the classes inside the packaged jars that are there in `web-inf/lib` folder of that application. Below is the straight forward configuration I have used. I looked at the plugin source code and it seems it scans the following: `getProject().getBuild().getOutputDirectory()`.

Is there anyways I can configure the plugin to scan the dependent jar files of the project?

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>reflections</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can easily run Reflections with any configuration you like, using, for example, gmaven-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    new org.reflections.Reflections("f.q.n")
                        .save("${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/reflections/${project.artifactId}-reflections.xml")
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So all you need to do is to use the right configuration, maybe in your specific case:

```groovy
def urls = org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper.forWebInfLib()
    new org.reflections.Reflections(urls)
        .save("${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/reflections/${project.artifactId}-reflections.xml")
```